# Java Set can not distinguish different objects

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, treeset

I have one class ***Human***, which contains two fields, ***age(int)***, and ***name(String)***. With eclipse, I override the ***hashCode()*** and ***equals()*** method with these two fields. I also create a **Comparator** based on the ***age*** field.

Now, I create a **TreeSet** object with the **Comparator** of age, and also two instances (with different fields values) of **Human** class. Then I add these two objects into the set, however, there are always only one object in the set.

For understanding the problem, I print out the hash value of these two objects, and find them are different. Then, I test their ***equals()*** method, it does output **false** when I compare two instances with different field values. So now, I cannot figure out why the **TreeSet** can't handle (differentiate) the problem. Can anyone give me some help ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TreeSet doesn't use `hashCode()` and `equals()` at all. It uses the comparator you pass as argument (or the `compareTo()` method of the objects if they are Comparable and you don't provide a comparator). Two objects are considered equal by a TreeSet if `compare()` (or`compareTo()`) returns 0 when comparing these two objects.

So if your comparator only compares the age of humans, all the humans with the same age will be considered equal. If you want humans to be considered equal when they have the same age and name, then the comparator should compare by age, and then compare by name if the age comparison returns 0.

Comment: Yes, well spotted. Use both fields in your compareTo() method. You want to sort by age, so order by name within age, then 2 names with the same age will still be sorted correctly but won't be considered equal (ie your compareTo will be consistent with equals).

Comment: But in the Java documentation, the **Comparator** Interface has only **compare()** method, not **compareTo()**, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. But if your objects implement Comparable, you don't need to pass a comparator to the constructor of the TreeSet. In this case, the TreeSet will compare the objects using their `compareTo` method.

Comment: So another question, for **HashSet** which uses ***equals()*** method. When I don't override the ***equals()*** method, why the **HashSet** can distinguish two different objects ? Note: my **Human** class implements the **Comparable** interface now !

Comment: All objects have an equals() and hashCode() methods, since java.lang.Object implements them. This default implementation only considers an object to be equal to itself.

Answer (score 2):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

> This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals
>   operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons
>   using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are
>   deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set,
>   equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract
>   of the Set interface.